# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementsbyTagName'

Tags: javascript

I am making a bookmarklet that should ask the user for an image source. The bookmarklet should then get all  tags on any website and change the src attribute of each  to whatever the prompt input was. Here is what I have so far:

```
javascript:
function ChangeImg(){
  var srcprompt = prompt("Type the url of the image that you want to put on this page.");
  document.getElementsbyTagName('img')[0].src = srcprompt;
}ChangeImg();
```

However, on the IE Javascript Console for Chrome, it says:
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getElementsbyTagName'

Is there something wrong with my script? Please help!

Comment: Case sensitivity is important. try `getElementsByTagName()`

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
document.getElementsbyTagName
```

To

```
document.getElementsByTagName
```

Notice `By`, it's not `by`. This is known as `camelcase`, each word or abbreviation begins with a capital letter. Camel case may start with a capital or, especially in programming languages, with a lowercase letter, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case). SO, an example could be `firstThenSecondThenThird`, first letter is lower case and then every words starts with capital letter.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is case sensitive. Each word (except the first) should be capitalised in that function name. `by` should be `By`